# ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: invalid %-encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova, heroku, ionic-framework

I am working on an `Ionic 2` app with `Rails 5 API` . I am trying to upload a file from my phone to the server. I user cordova `FileTransfer` plugin for this. From the `FileTransfer` [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/)

> The FileTransfer object provides a way to upload files using an HTTP
>   multi-part POST or PUT request, and to download files.

This is my ionic code to upload the image,

```
  fileUpload(filePath: string,apiEndpoint: string){
    this.fileTransfer = new Transfer();
    let fileName = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    let options = Object.assign( this.httpHeader(),{chunkedMode: false, fileName: fileName});
    return this.fileTransfer.upload(filePath, apiEndpoint, options)
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

It gets the filepath and upload it to my rails backend . In rails I have,

```
  def update_picture
    @user = current_user.update_picture(params[:file])
    if @user.save
      render_create_success
    else
      render_create_errorn
    end
  end
```

Everything works fine in my local machine in development and production environment. But once I push it to `heroku` , it throws an error.

```
Started POST "/v1/update_picture" for
 ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: invalid %-encoding ("file"; filename="tmp_IMG-20170321-WA0000972448512.jpg"
 Content-Type: image/jpeg
����JFIF��C
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/query_parser.rb:72:in `rescue in parse_nested_query'
```

If I am correct, `Content-Type` should be `multipart/form-data` and this error should occur when data is url encoded. My project is stuck on this issue. I would like to know,

1. What is causing this error if its not url encoded?
2. How can I debug this? There is no issues when I use it in local machine but on heroku.

   **Edit**

I had a similar error in development when the `chunkMode` option in `file upload` was turned on. I set it to false , and the error was gone. If you would like to know anymore details , I will add them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. Its a bug in cordova `FileTransfer` plugin `1.6.0`. It forces chunkedMode  on over https connection . Updating to `1.6.2` fixed the issue.